# how to create custom layout those view (for ex Imageview)arrange in arc shape?

Tags: android

here is my custom view sample code.....

```
    public class AspectImageView extends ImageView {

        public AspectImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public AspectImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public AspectImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            //Figure out the aspect ratio of the image content
            int widthSize = 0;
            int desiredSize;
            float aspect;
            Drawable d = getDrawable();
            if (d == null) {
                desiredSize = 0;
                aspect = 1f;
            } else {
                desiredSize = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
                aspect = (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth() / (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            }
            //Get the width based on the measure specs
            int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
            int specSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            switch (specMode) {
                case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
                    //Big as we want to be
                    widthSize = desiredSize;
                    break;
                case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                    //Big as we want to be, up to the spec
                    widthSize = Math.min(desiredSize, specSize);
                    break;
                case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                    //Must be the spec size
                    widthSize = specSize;
                    break;
            }

            //Calculate height based on aspect
            int heightSize = (int)(widthSize / aspect);

            //Make sure the height we want is not too large
            specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST || specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                //If our measurement exceeds the max height, shrink back
                if (heightSize > specSize) {
                    heightSize = specSize;
                    widthSize = (int)(heightSize * aspect);
                }
            }

            //MUST do this to store the measurements
            setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);
        }
```

Please anyone hlep me.  I want to arrange 7 imageview in arc shape in custom layout, when on button click remove one imageView that time 6 imageview rearrange in arc shape ...

Comment: could you please provide any kind of sketch how it should look like? You want to arrange views in a circle, or in a semi-circle arc, or in an arc of given inner angle, or...